# PHP mail not sending (possible macOS Server or Firewall issue?)

Tags: network, server.app, firewall, php, webserver

This is a relatively complex problem and LONG description, so bear with me. Please ask questions in the comments if you think I can clarify something. I am hosting multiple websites on a single computer running macOS Server (version 5.3.1 running on macOS 10.12.6). On one of these websites, I have a PHP form that is supposed to send me an email when submitted (but doesn't). I have three test platforms: a server at college (heavily regulated enterprise network), a server at home that hosts the website (relatively secured and managed personal network), and a laptop with me while I'm staying with friends abroad (relatively unmanaged, likely less secured, personal network). All three devices are Apple computers with macOS Server set up.

What I know works:
- I have my spam filter set to accept emails from this PHP script.
- PHP is enabled in the Websites section of MacOS Server.
- When I first began building the site (August), the PHP code sent me emails.
- The PHP script (in its current form) works.
- I am currently staying with friends abroad, and if I run this script from my laptop via terminal (`php ~/path/to/script.php`) from here, it works.

What I know doesn't work:
- If I fill out the form online the php script does not work.
- Running the script via terminal on the server at my home fails.
- Running the script via terminal on the server at my college also fails.

Note that the PHP mail function returns success every time, even if I never receive an email.

It's these last few points that make me think that the problem is with a firewall. Since I launched the sites (about a month ago), I have had to close a number of service ports I was using when building the sites (screen sharing, ssh, and some others) on the server at home after bots tried to hack it, and was wondering if this could have led to the problem or if it is something entirely different.

**Question: Is there a way I can get my PHP mail script to function as expected?**

Maybe more useful information: port scans!

Here is an nmap port scan of the public IP of the website:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp  open     domain
80/tcp  open     http
111/tcp filtered rpcbind
311/tcp open     asip-webadmin
443/tcp open     https
625/tcp open     apple-xsrvr-admin
```

Here is an nmap port scan of my laptop (localhost) (I will try to get a port scan of the public IP of the network soon and add that to the question, but this is not possible at the moment):

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
88/tcp    open  kerberos-sec
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
464/tcp   open  kpasswd5
548/tcp   open  afp
749/tcp   open  kerberos-adm
999/tcp   open  garcon
1021/tcp  open  exp1
1023/tcp  open  netvenuechat
1947/tcp  open  sentinelsrm
2049/tcp  open  nfs
3031/tcp  open  eppc
3322/tcp  open  active-net
3323/tcp  open  active-net
3324/tcp  open  active-net
3325/tcp  open  active-net
4444/tcp  open  krb524
5900/tcp  open  vnc
7000/tcp  open  afs3-fileserver
7001/tcp  open  afs3-callback
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49156/tcp open  unknown
49158/tcp open  unknown
49159/tcp open  unknown
49160/tcp open  unknown
49161/tcp open  unknown
49163/tcp open  unknown
49167/tcp open  unknown
```

Comment: Quick test : turn off the firewall and test again...

Comment: I hesitant to vote to close as off topic, but I don't see how this is an Apple issue per se.  It seems more like a PHP issue.  Wouldn't this be a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: @Allan possibly, but I wasn't sure. Should I close here and open there, or get it transferred somehow? My only thought was that because it was all on Apple hardware/software, that it might be appropriate here (and I know the community here)

Comment: I'll flag for the moderators to migrate.  No sense in retyping all that....

Comment: Let’s keenthis here. It’s absolutely on topic here PHO on macos is very fine to ask. If someone posts this to a server fault room and people there approve migration , we could do it then but I’m not clear it’s on topic there. They migrate OS X questions here all the time like this one

Comment: @SolarMike the firewall I'm talking about is the one built into the Time Capsule acting as the router at the house, not the one built into the computer. Although thinking about it now, it probably doesn't care much about outgoing connections. Could I have closed a port I need open by mistake?